# IRC receiving 0x02 value, treat as formatting?

Tags: c#, ascii, richtextbox, rtf, irc

Once I register a nick with a **IRC server** (in this case **Freenode**), I receive a message like this:

```
:NickServ!NickServ@services. NOTICE IRCLIBtester :*IRCLIBtester* is not a registered nickname.
```

I have inserted asterisks(*) where the weird `0x02` byte is received. Since the servers 005 `ISUPPORT` contained

```
CASEMAPPING=rfc1459 CHARSET=ascii
```

I assumed the messages would be pure ASCII, but in ASCII 0x02 is the Start-of-text marker. Looking at how other clients (in this case HexChat) parsed the string I noticed they took it as a "bold-font" toggle, so the nick would be in bold. Is this practice? And if so, which format is this?

My first thought is `RTF`, but since I display the text in a `richtextbox(C#)`, it should have parsed the `0x02` byte itself right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0x02 is the code for BOLD in IRC. These are undocumented in the RFC (1459 and onwards) but can be found via google.

You may find other format codes here: http://forum.egghelp.org/viewtopic.php?t=3867